# Scrolling back to field which was last selected - Android LinearLayout

Tags: android, focus, android-linearlayout

I have a ScrollView with a LinearLayout in it. The layout has a number of views which (are LinearLayouts) with different controls in them. All fine and dandy. The problem starts when I select a control containing a TextView (giving it focus) and then scroll down and choose a control which pops up another screen (Activity). When I return I want to show the control which activated the screen (Activity) in the view, but instead Android scrolls back up (which can be pretty far) to the TextView that previously had focus. I have tried a million things (clearing focus on the TextView, setting on the other control) to no affect (unless the TextView originally did not have focus, in which case all is fine).

The resulting effect is that you do something (like take a picture) and find yourself scrolled back up to the top of all the controls.

I have attempted to fix this when I return from the activity with the following with no effect:

```html
// Clear current focus
View currentFocus = mFormLayout.getFocusedChild();
if (currentFocus != null) {
  currentFocus.clearFocus();
}
    

// Set the focus to this field.
formField.requestFocus();
```

thanks